# Selenium web driver can't find element

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

I have a problem when trying to find a Web Element using Selenium web driver.

I've done this with two pages, which both of the elements I'm wanting to grab are in lots of classes, ids, etc.

Here's the first one element, which I had no problems finding.

```
<input type="text" class="input-large" name="host" value="">
```

Which I used this to grab:

```
WebElement HtmlHost = driver.findElement(By.name("host"));
```

Now here's where my problem begins. I'm now trying to grab this:

```
<button type="submit" name="bootBtn" class="btn btn-inverse btn-large">Start hashing</button>
```

Which I've tried grabbing with all of these functions, but none have been able to find the element.

```
driver.findElement(By.partialLinkText("Start "));
driver.findElement(By.linkText("Start Hashing"));
driver.findElement(By.name("bootBtn"));
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("button[type='submit']"));
```

What do you suggest I do?

Thanks.

Comment: Those all look like they should work, but how about trying `By.CssSelector("button[type='submit']")`?

Comment: No that doesn't work either. Anymore suggestions?

Comment: The methods that rely on link text won't work because you are looking for a `button` whereas the methods that search by link text only search for `a` element. The search by name and the search by css selector should work. Is the button showing up on the page only after something else makes it appear? Also, what is the exact error message you get?

Comment: The button is there when you load the page up. I'm getting the NoSuchElementException error.

Comment: is the element within a frame?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I found the problem, and I feel pretty stupid that I missed this. The site I was trying to find the button requires you to login. I already knew this as I've coded the login process, but when I created this new void I placed it before the login process.

Sorry to waste time, thanks for help!

Comment: Please delete your question then, as this is not useful to anyone else.

Answer (score 0):

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[contains(text(),'Start hashing')]"));
This will grab the element.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
Thread.sleep(2000);
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@type='submit']"));
```